# When connected through a router, a new gateway appears, and I lose my internet connection

Tags: windows-7, router, internet-connection

I have two computers connected to a router, connected to my ADSL modem by PPPoE.
One of those computrs use Windows XP, the other uses Windows 7.
The computer using Windows 7 keeps getting limited or no connectivity, and I can't use it to connect to the internet. Connecting the computer to the modem without the router 'in the way' worked, and I was able to use the internet - which led me to believe that the problem is with my router. However, I have changed my router, and the problem persists.

(Just to be clear: the computer using Windows XP can connect to the internet without any problem). This entire question is about the PC using Windows 7.

The only symptom of this problem is that when I see my network devices, in addition to my router (which appears as "Network 4", or something of the sort), I also see an "Unidentified Network". When using ipconfig to check the problem, I see a second gateway, with the IP 0.0.0.0, in addition to the IP of my router.

Comment: This may or may not be connected: I've disabled the Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper/Responder, and upon restarting - my computer was able to connect to the internet once more. The situation persisted even after turning this on. The "Unidentified Network" disappeared from my Network and Sharing center.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: ok, the Topology Discovery was a dead end.

Comment: The PC using Windows 7, I assume it's a desktop?  How many NIC's does it have?  Are any of them wireless?  From the Windows 7 PC, connect to the either Edimax router, do `Start -> Run -> cmd /k ipconfig /all` and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/765aa1c6-dd9a-4447-9de0-aecc41498b04) look relevant? Unfortunately, the linked "very good explanation" is no longer accessible, but a few posters seem to have resolved the problem by [forcibly removing Adobe CS3's Bonjour service](http://forums.adobe.com/message/1634806#1634806).

Comment: Thank you! It appears to fit the scenario at hand. I wish to wait a few days to see that the problem does not persists (since it was inconsistent, before) before accepting the answer. Then I will also edit the question to emphasize the problem.

Thanks!